# Get image format from Scrimage Image instance

Tags: scala, scrimage

I'm working with scrimage right now, and I need to get the image format from the file, as right now, if a GIF is uploaded, it will not become an animated JPEG. I need to be able to tell if the image file is a GIF so I know to not use the Format.JPEG writer. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

In release 2.0.0-M2 you can do

```
val format : Option[Format] = FormatDetector.detect(in)
```

where in is an input stream.